# How to Install the AddThis Tools on Magento 2

Tags: magento-2.1

vendor `http://www.addthis.com/academy/how-to-install-the-addthis-tools-to-magento` don't have Magento-2 integration guide on their site I tried to add that way in Magento-2 ( script link to paste ) but that didn't work and script is there as normal HTML tag.

```
<div class="addthis_toolbox addthis_default_style ">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://s7.addthis.com/js/300/addthis_widget.js#pubid=xa-5054e6c6502d114f" async="async"></script>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Write this code to Add **Share this Button** in your site in to the **PHTMl** File.

```
<div class="addthis_inline_share_toolbox"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//s7.addthis.com/js/300/addthis_widget.js#pubid=ra-5bc5ca19700dbe94"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

On the template you want to have that just add this:

```
<div class="addthis_sharing_toolbox"></div>
<!-- Go to www.addthis.com/dashboard to customize your tools -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="//s7.addthis.com/js/300/addthis_widget.js#pubid=xa-5054e6c6502d114f"></script>
```